# header file .h not find by main.cpp in a ros package

Tags: package, include, ros

Hi i have my ROS package:

motion_planner
|
|--src
|   |-main.cpp
|   |-Kineamtic.h
|
|--include
|-motion_planner
|-Kinematic.h

So my CMakeList is:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.2)
project(motion_planner)

add_compile_options(-std=c++11)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  roscpp
  rospy
  std_msgs
)

catkin_package(
  #INCLUDE_DIRS include
  #LIBRARIES ${PROJECT_NAME}
  CATKIN_DEPENDS roscpp rospy std_msgs message_runtime
  #DEPENDS system_lib
)

include_directories(
  include
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  ${Eigen_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)


add_library(Kinematic
  src/Kinematic.cpp
)

target_link_libraries(inverse_kinematic_node 
Kinematic
${catkin_LIBRARIES}
${Eigen_LIBRARIES})
```

When i made catkin_make there are not errors, this means that Kinematic.cpp find Kinematic.h. But when i run Kinematic.cpp:
g++ main.cpp -o test
it return the error: fatal error: motion_planner/Kinematic.h: No such file or directory

I search online solution but i haven't find anything that could halp me.

Answer (score 0):

The `g++` command you're using only includes a single source file. The doesn't directly give any information to the compiler about extra directories with headers that you've created. However, that information is specified in your `CMakeLists.txt` with the call to `include_directories`. If you want to add extra include directories to your manual build you should use the `-I` flag. For example it should look something like `g++ main.cpp -Iinclude -o test`